# Use DisplayFormat in Asp.Net Core to display elapsed time

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a ViewModel class with a column, named `Duration` that contains the amount of hours between two `DatetTime` columns (calculated in the query):

```
public Int32 Duration { get; set; }
```

I was hoping that I could use an annotation to display the amount of elapsed time, in days and hours (e.g. `0d 15h`).

This doesn't work:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd hh}")]
```

The logic using a `TimeSpan`:

```
DateTime s;
DateTime.TryParse("2015-03-18 15:00:42.920",out s);
DateTime e;
DateTime.TryParse("2015-03-19 06:52:44.440",out e);
TimeSpan t = e - s;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}d {1}h", t.Days, t.Hours));
```

Is there a way to use data annotations (alone) to achieve this?

Comment: No. Data annotations must be constants, which means you cannot do calculation like this.

Comment: That said, if your `Duration` property was actually a `TimeSpan` instead of an `int`, you can use your format string directly.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, are you suggesting having a model that maps directly to the query's data types (including `Int32` for the `Duration`), then using Automapper to cast that data set into a view-model that has `Duration` as a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: However, you want/need to do it. Simply, with your property as an int, you cannot use `DisplayFormat` with it to achieve the format you're looking for, as you cannot perform the necessary calculations to get there. You can use `DisplayFormat` successfully if your property is a `TimeSpan`. If you need a custom view model to achieve that, then that's what you'll have to do, or just do the calculation and string formatting manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decide to add a function to the view:

```
public string Elapsed(Int32 duration)
{
    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromHours(duration);
    return String.Format("{0}d {1}h", t.Days, t.Hours);
}
```

then reference it:

```
<td> @Elapsed(item.Duration) </td>
```